Loading into a scene causes saved objects to swap positions with eachother
First time implementing a save/load function in a game and having an issue.
I have a list of objects that have their positions saved when the application quits and changes scene, these objects get re-loaded during void Start.
Quitting and relaunching the application works perfectly.
Switching scenes (via UI buttons) causes the loaded objects to switch places with each other.  This also only seems to effect objects that have not moved during run time.
I run the same save/load functions when quitting and changing scenes so i am at a bit of a loss with why my objects are jumbling up.
I have tried praying to every god I can think of but I must have missed a couple cus nothing I try works
How the game looks when starting fresh (green numbers correspond to how many wire pieces are in the stack)

How the game looks after switching scenes and coming back

Any advice/suggestions are appreciated. Thanks!

Quite hard to tell for anyone without seeing your code and hierarchy don't you think? There seems to be more things wrong then just objects switching places .. there are also way too many objects meaning something in your loading is broken - could it be that something assumes a first scene load (before objects are saved) and just generates a random set and then you also additionally trigger the loading ?

Without seeing your saving and loading logic we can only guess.
My guess would be, that you don't save the index on which place which piece was placed before saving and they might be stored in an unordered way e.g. by being put into a Set like structure.
